# Clojure - extract values from a vector of hashmaps

Tags: clojure

Wracking my brain this afternoon trying to figure this one out. I'm fairly new to Clojure and Lisp in general. I have a data structure that is a vector of maps and I want to get all the values for a particular key out of all of the maps into another vector.

For example, let's say this is the vector of maps bound to myvec:

```
[ { "key1" "value1" "key2" "value2"} {"key1" "value3" "key2" "value4"} ]
```

and I want a vector that looks like

```
[ "value1" "value3" ]
```

made up of all the values of the key "key1"

The only way I could think of to do it is

```
(for [i (range (count(myvec)))] ((myvec i) "key1"))
```

Is there an easier way? It seems like there must be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`(map #(get % "key1") myvec)` should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. I am pulling the keys and values out of a query. I get back something like "State: Closed" and am setting up a hashmap like {"State" "Closed"}. That's why I'm not using :keywords. Or is there still some way to use keywords?

Comment: Deleted my old comment recommending turning strings into keywords. I thought it was a good idea 9 years ago, but no longer do. Keywords are best used for literals in source files. If you're getting the data externally, leave them as strings.

Answer (score 10):

```
(let [v [{"key1" "value1", "key2" "value2"} {"key1" "value3", "key2" "value4"}]]
  (vec (map #(% "key1") v)))
```

If you use keywords for your keys:

```
(let [v [{:key1 "value1", :key2 "value2"} {:key1 "value3", :key2 "value4"}]]
  (vec (map :key1 v)))
```

If you don't want to include `nil` values when the maps don't have the given key:

```
(let [v [{:key1 "value1", :key2 "value2"} {:key1 "value3", :key2 "value4"} {:key2 "value5"}]]
  (vec (keep :key1 v)))
```